# Unintuitive nested class inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc

Is the following code valid with C++ standard? It's strange that C::B would work because struct B is in A's namespace. But it does compile fine with gcc.

```
struct A { struct B {}; };
struct C : public A::B {};
struct D : public C::B {};
```

If this is standard conforming C++, what are reasonable applications for this construct?
Thanks.

Comment: Nitpick; `A` does not define a namespace.  `::` is the scope resolution operator, which is also used for namespaces, but not only for namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's valid C++.  A class in its own scope (so both `B` and `B::B` refer to the same class `B`), and a class's parent class is in its own scope.  So since `B` is in `C`'s scope and `B` is in its own scope, `C::B` refers to `B` which is `A::B`.

(Side note: do not confuse a *namespace* with a *scope*.)

C++03 §9 paragraph 2 says:

> A *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the *class-name* is seen.
>   The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.
>   For purposes of access checking, the *injected-class-name* is treated as if it were a public member name.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you could do this either: `struct E : public A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::B::B {};`

Answer (score 0):

This is standard conforming C++.

A reasonable application of nested classes (through scope resolution) is the pImpl design pattern (though you can implement it in a way that will not demonstrate nested classes, but here I choose to demonstrate nested classes).
Note: Inheritance is one of the facets that can be confusing but the real concept is the scope resolution of a nested class.

```
//ExposedClass in Exposed.h

class CExposedClass
{
public:
CExposedClass();
~CExposedClass();
void doThis();
void doThat();

private:
class CXImpl;
CXImpl *pImpl;

};

//ExposedClass Impl in Exposed.cpp

#include "Exposed.h"

class CExposedClass::CXImpl
{
 int someData;
};

CExposedClass::CExposedClass():pImpl(new CXImpl()){}
CExposedClass::~CExposedClass(){delete pImpl;}
void CExposedClass::doThis(){}
void CExposedClass::doThat(){}
```

class defined within the scope of one class is addressed from another scope using scope resolution.